# Parsing server response with $.parseJSON failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got these two simple functions:

```
function getBatchSliceInfo(batch_num){
    //get the batch slice info for the batch_num
    alert('batch num is ' + batch_num); //returns the batch_num correctly
    $.getJSON("statistics_batchdb.jsp", {batch_number: batch_num, slice_stats: 'true'}, showTable);
}

function showTable(data){
    $("#table_slice_stats").hide();
    if(data.error){
        console.log("Something went wrong"); 
    }
    var jo = $.parseJSON(data); 
    alert('This JSON object has this many elements: '  + jo.length); 
    $.each(jo[0], function (i, val){
        alert('This i value is' + i );
        alert('This val value is' + val);
    }); 
    $("#table_slice_stats").show();
}
```

So I call getBatchSliceInfo on the click of a button and we get the JSON.

The response seems to be correct, so server side I'm alright.

[image: screenshot]

However, I'm not passing that response correctly to showTable. "data" appears to be null because in the console I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null batch_statistics_new.jsp:274
showTable batch_statistics_new.jsp:274
o jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
w jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
d jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
```

I'm sure this is a very simple syntax question but I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: try without parseJSON i guess it is already like yo = data, and for debuggin use console.dir(data)

Comment: You're not passing JSON to `$.parseJSON`. You're passing a JavaScript object that was the result of your JSON already having been parsed.

Comment: @johnSmith both you and cookie monster are totally right.

Answer (score 1):

check your `data`

```
var data= [{slice_name:Nutrion,iteration_zero:.....},{......},{......}]
```

After convert to json Format.your data become like this,

```
var data= {[{slice_name:Nutrion,iteration_zero:.....},{......},{......}]} //It not json format.
```

if you tring to use length property it throwing an exceptions.so,do the same think without parsing into json.